# Visa category for Netherlands if attending a workshop on Indian passport

Tags: indian-citizens, study, australian-residents

I am a research student planning to attend a workshop in the Netherlands and then visit France for 2 days as a tourist. Currently, I live in Australia and have an Indian passport. Which visa category should I pick to apply for the Schengen visa?

Comment: @Traveller did you mean https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/netherlands/australia/english/#short-stay-Schengen ?

Answer (score 3):

The Schengen Type C short-stay visa is not issued in various classes as are the visas of many countries (notably including Australia).  The point of indicating a "purpose of the journey" is to guide the officer who is evaluating the application.  It also determines what supporting documents you will need to include in the application.

Looking at the available categories on the application form, I would probably choose "other (please specify)" and write "academic workshop" or "research workshop" or something like that.  Noting that the form asks for "purpose(s) of the journey," I would *also* select tourism.

On [the relevant VFS Global page](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/netherlands/australia/english/#short-stay-Schengen), there is a category for "conference, cultural, religious or political event," which seems the most appropriate.  (I found the VFS Global page through a link on the Dutch government's [Applying for a Schengen visa for the Netherlands in Australia](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/visa-the-netherlands/schengen-visa/apply-australia) page.)

The "conference etc." category shares its "required documents" checklist with the business category, which helps to explain why the second of these requirements assumes that there is a "company" involved:

> 5.5. Official invitation letter from a firm, host organisation, educational establishment or an authority to attend meetings, conferences or events, containing detailed information
> concerning:
>
> - address and contacts of the inviting entity;
> - name and position of the countersigning person;
> - purpose and duration of stay;
> - person or entity who will bear the travel and living costs (if applicable).
>
> 5.6. Documents proving the applicants employment status in the company (for example, contract, proof of social security contribution).

(The requirements that I've omitted concern things such as proof of financial means, health insurance, and the like that are common to all categories.)

If you have any questions about how to meet these requirements in your circumstances, the workshop organizers may be able to advise you, especially the person who provides you with the official invitation letter, assuming that yours isn't the first such letter they've produced.  If they can't answer your questions, you can post them here.

You should probably also have a look at the tourism checklist, which for example asks for

> 5.5 A document from the establishment providing the accommodation or any other appropriate document indicating the accommodation envisaged.

That is, they'll want evidence of your accommodations in France for those two days (as well as evidence of how you plan to get there and back).